# Java selectively copy files from a zip such that file timestamp should be preserved

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-compress

I have followed following approach to decompress a zip using [apache commons compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/examples.html):

But since I am using  `OutputStream` & `IOUtils.copy(ais, os);` **(code below)** to unzip and copy file, the timestamp is not preserved. Is there another way to directly copy the file from the zip such that file timestamp can be preserved.

```
try (ArchiveInputStream ais =
         asFactory.createArchiveInputStream(
           new BufferedInputStream(
             new FileInputStream(archive)))) {

        System.out.println("Extracting!");
        ArchiveEntry ae;
        while ((ae = ais.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            // check if file needs to be extracted {}
            if(!extract())
                continue;

            if (ae.isDirectory()) {
                File dir = new File(archive.getParentFile(), ae.getName());
                dir.mkdirs();
                continue;
            }

            File f = new File(archive.getParentFile(), ae.getName());
            File parent = f.getParentFile();
            parent.mkdirs();
            try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f)) {
                IOUtils.copy(ais, os);
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException innerIoe) {
                ...
            }
        }

        ais.close();
        if (!archive.delete()) {
            System.out.printf("Could not remove archive %s%n",
                               archive.getName());
            archive.deleteOnExit();
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ...
    }
```

**EDIT:** With the help of [jbx's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/340088/jbx) answer below, following change will make it work.

```
IOUtils.copy(ais, os);
os.close();
outFile.setLastModified(entry.getLastModifiedTime().toMillis()); // this line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `lastModifiedTime` file attribute using NIO. **Do it to the file exactly after you write it (after you close it)**. The operating system would have marked its last modified time to the current time at that point.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html

You will need to get the last modified time from the zip file, so maybe using NIO's 
Zip Filesystem Provider` to browse and extract files from the archive would be better than your current approach (unless the APIs you are using provide you the same information).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html

Comment: It worked. What I was doing wrong was : `outFile.setLastModified(entry.getLastModifiedTime().toMillis());` before line : `IOUtils.copy(ais, os);`. Moving it after `os.close()` did the trick. Your statement **Do it to the file exactly after you write it (after you close it)** was the key